# How to find if a relationship of correct type and parameters exists in Neo4j using python neo4jrestclient

Tags: python, neo4j

Is there a way using the python neo4jrestclient library to determine if two nodes are connected by a specific relationship?  I can only provide properties and values as parameters (and not nodes or relationship types) in a call to the query method so after getting a result set, I need to iterate over it and check if the start, end and relationship type are all correct.

```
ridx = gdb.relationships.indexes['relationship_auto_index']
results = ridx.query('flag:true')
filtered = [r for r in results if r.type=='Link']
# .. code to check start and end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

neo4jrestclient supports [cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-query-lang.html) as query language. So if you have some means of identifying the start and end node, e.g. index lookup, you can query directly:

```
START n = node:mynodes(key='someuuidperhaps'), m = node:mynodes(key='otheruuidperhaps')
MATCH n -[r:KNOWS]-m
WHERE r.flag = True
return r
```

You can match on the direction of the relationship, using `->` or `<-`.

In addition to that, I'd recommend [py2neo](https://py2neo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which I consider to have the better API.

Comment: Thanks, I was focused on getting the answer from the library, wanting to avoid switching between from library to Cypher, but this seems to be the way.  I'll take a look at py2neo.